# Conversion failed when converting a character string into a date or time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

The table I am using has 3 `nvarchar(MAX)` columns and 1 `datetime` column. I am getting this error when I am executing the following insert statement:-

> Conversion failed when converting a character string into a date or time

```
     DateTime date = System.DateTime.Now;        
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into chats values('" + chatFrom + "','" + chatTo + "',@msg,'"+date+"')", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("msg", msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would probably use parameters for all of those variables since that concatenated string is a little messy.

Secondly, in my experience SQL can be much pickier about the format of the date/time string than the programming language. You might try doing something like `date.ToString("ddMMyy")` perhaps using a more appropriate format string for your particular database and the level of precision you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameters for the date value:

```
 DateTime date = System.DateTime.Now;        
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into chats values('" + chatFrom + "','" + chatTo + "',@msg, @date)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("msg", msg);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is most likely because of the layout of your default date format.

SQL Server cannot tell whether '01/04/2015' is the first of April or the fourth of January.

Change this line:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into chats values('" + chatFrom + "','" + chatTo + "',@msg,'"+ date.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") +"')", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("msg", msg);
```

To make it unambiguous.

Comment: It will break on non-US systems

Comment: It shouldn't. The ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy") is forcing the month part ot be three character letters, eg: JAN, FEB, MAR, etc and the year 4 digits, so SQL Server will always interpret it as a month and year regardless of the local system datetime format. @Landscape Penguin's answer above (ToString("ddMMyy")) will not work in non-US systems though as the day and month are still ambiguous.